# Replace configuration line with Ansible

Tags: php, linux, automation, vagrant, ansible

**File:**

[app.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/app.php)

**Description:**

I want replace the line 11 with:

`$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);`

Instead of:

`$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);`

**main.yml file:**

I'm trying to do this, but isn't work:

`- name: Change to Symfony development enviroment for reflect the changes directly on the vagrant box
  replace: dest=/vagrant/symfony-standard/web/app.php regexp='$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);' replace='$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);' backup=yes`

**Terminal:**

`TASK [symfony-standard : Change to Symfony development enviroment for reflect the changes directly on the vagrant box] ***
task path: /vagrant/playbooks/roles/symfony-standard/tasks/main.yml:49
ok: [default] => {"changed": false, "msg": ""}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to escape the $ sign, try to do something like this:

```
- name:  Change to Symfony development enviroment for reflect the changes directly on the vagrant box
  replace:
    dest: /vagrant/symfony-standard/web/app.php
    regexp: \$kernel = new.*$
    replace: $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

Please also try this one:

```
\$kernel = new AppKernel\('prod', false\);
```